# How to add a web view to the split view based application

Tags: xcode, ipad

How to add a web view to the root view controller in the split view based application. 
The following is the code which i am using,

[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"rightview"ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];

but in the output its not producing any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it looks like an local html, you can also try doing it with loadHTMLString method like

```
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

load htmlString with the html content of your bundle html file.

Answer (score 0):

You may also create a request using:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"link"];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[viewController webView] loadRequest:req];
```

Or something along those lines. You're going to have to tweak things a bit to have everything communicate properly. Just make sure you declare your webView in the App Delegate...